# Angular 5, what is the best way to share a form between different components

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a main form in a service called "MainService"- (the real form is much longer). 
Looks like this-

```
export class MainService {

 this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            A: ['', Validators.required],
            B: '',
            C: '',
            D: this.formBuilder.array([]),
            E: this.formBuilder.array([]),
            F:'',
            G: this.formBuilder.array([]),
            H: this.formBuilder.array([]),
            I: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        });
    }
}
```

Different components look at the form's values and change the form by importing the service. the template looks like-

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [formControl]="MainService.A">
    <mat-label></mat-label>
</mat-form-field>
```

Is it the best way to share the form between the different components?
Each component represents a different form control in the form so they must look at the same form.

For example this is a form for a student to fill many details about an article he read (name of the book, number of pages, authors, topics and so on). Each detail of the book is a form control in the main form, and each component is responsible for updating a different form control (component that represents the name input, component that represents the authors input..)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a little less abstract? I understand that exposing your actual data or use case may be undesirable, but is there a way that you can speak about the form relationships in the context of (for example) a grocery store (recipe list, shopping card, etc) so that what you're aiming to accomplish is clearer?

Comment: The form is for example for a student to fill a lot of details about an article he read- name of the book, number of pages, authors, topics and so on. Each detail of the book is a form control in the main form, and each component is responsible for updating it's section (component that represents the name input, component that represents the authors input..) is it more clear?

Comment: I think your current approach is legitimate.

Comment: I added details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

A nice approach (in my opinion) is to create a small component containing the form you wish to share, and interact with it using `@Input` and `@Output` properties.

For example, the `@Input`s can be used to setup initial form state, and the `@Output`s can be used to react to form events (if using reactive forms).

```
<my-shared-form
  [initialState]="{ control1: 'nice'}"
  (formValuesChanged)="doSomeThingWithValidForm($event)"
></my-shared-form>
```

Form component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared-form',
  templateUrl: './my-shared-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-shared-form.component.scss'],
})
export class MySharedFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  public initialState: { [key: string]: any };

  @Output()
  public formValuesChanged = new EventEmitter<{ [key: string]: any }>();

  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      control1: [this.initialState.control1 ? this.initialState.control1 : ''],
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
      this.formValuesChanged.emit(val);
    });
  }
}
```

Form component template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" formControlName="control1">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks, but how the different components will get access to this form? through input? this components will be the base of the rest of the components?

Comment: you have to use NgRX or just services if the components are siblings or do full reactive development

Comment: @danda in the example I gave the form control values are outputted and can be accessed by listening to the event (formValuesChanged)="doSomeThingWithValidForm($event)"

Comment: thanks! I was looking for a solution with subjects, I heard that can do the work.

Comment: @danda yeah EventEmitters (typically used with `@Output` decorators) are actually just wrappers around rxjs Subjects, check it out: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Notice the class extends Subject.